# Find the value in terms of $n$

Tags: summation

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} 3^k \binom{n}{k}$$

I have tried filling in and simplifying but the following was not correct:
$$1 + 3n + 3^2 \dbinom{n}{2} + \cdots + 3^n$$

Comment: It is just $4^n$, by the binomial theorem applied to $(3+1)^n$.

Comment: Why are we using (3+1)

Comment: Take $a=3$ and $b=1$ in $(a+b)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}a^k b^{n-k}.$